# Branch Specific Settings Files For Git(Hub) That Won't Merge

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have an application with the following branch setup:

- production
- staging
- dev-a
- dev-b
- dev-c (etc)

There are certain settings files specific to each branch (and deploy environment). I want these files to remain in version control (so I can make changes to them on a specific branch and push etc), but I want to be able to merge (or rebase) between branches without these files being pulled in the merge - ever.

For example, assume `production` has `config.txt` with:

```
key=production-api-key
```

and `staging` has `config.txt` with:

```
key=staging-api-key
```

and so on and so forth. If I make changes to any files in staging, push to GitHub, open a PR, and then merge, I want `config.txt` ignored in the merge. Also, if I change `config.txt` on `staging`, and push to GitHub, and another developer on the project pulls the changes, I want them to see the new, modified version of `config.txt` that I pushed to the `staging` branch (obviously only while on the `staging` branch).

`.gitignore` is not what I am looking for here, seeing as this will ignore any changes across all branches, and whatever local version of the file I have will forever be what is in use, as well as the fact that any changes I make to them won't be reflected when other developers try to pull the changes to a particular branch.

I've considered using `git update-index --assume-unchanged config.txt`, and while this will allow different versions of `config.txt` on every branch (assuming I commit the changes before running the `--assume-unchanged`), it won't allow me to update the files, and if I open a PR, the changes are merged in.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do NOT use --assume-unchanged. It means something different. It means you promise to Git that it does not need to waste stat cycles checking for changes (which it will eventually). The documentation is being updated to be clearer about that distinction given the number of misunderstandings about its use. Try using the gitignore or excludes feature and then track/untrack only at the point of commit.

Answer (score 0):

.gitignore is normally committed on each branch as part of the file structure, so you can have different ignore lists in each branch, just as you have different code in each branch. You just need to remember to set the ignore list appropriately (or comment out the ones not needed).

Comment: It's the same file in every branch, and I need the individual branches to know what their versions are (which will be different). Even if I .gitignore the file (after committing an initial version), and then make changes to it, and switch branches, all branches will have this newly modified version, not their own versions. .gitignore prevents me from making changes to my individual branches (which I want to be able to do) and persists any changes I do make in between branches (which I want to not have happen).

Comment: Just because it's the same file, doesn't mean you can't have distinct .gitignore files in each branch. When you change branches you may need to 'untrack' the range of files from the index and then add/stat the relevant ones (which will be based on the .gitignore) back. A simple alias can hang it all together.

Comment: oops double entry deleted (Chrome finger trouble)

Comment: The way to untrack a file is `git rm --cache -- <file>` - check the manual for blobbing options. You may find it useful to create an alias of that.